# How to hide fab on clicking anywhere in screen?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using [Floating Action Button](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton). I am using this library because I needed inbox style fab. The problem is, I can close the floating action menu only on clicking the bottom fab. What I need is, if I click anywhere else on the screen, then also the fab should collapse as happens in Inbox app. How to achieve this behavior? Is there any attributes in this library that I can use or do I need to implement that behavior on my own?

Comment: Why not set its visibility Visibity.GONE? You can add that to onClick behaviour of anything on that view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The library has a method `setClosedOnTouchOutside(boolean close)` which you can use.

```
floatingActionMenu.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);
```

But this will only be workable for floatingActionMenu's covered area. If you wanna close it by clicking anywhere in the layout then you should try [this](http://anakinfoxe.com/blog/2016/01/31/how-to-collapse-floatingactionmenu-when-click-the-area-outside-of-it/).

Answer (score 2):

Misho Zhghenti's solution for the use of `compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.8.0'` isn't right as it specifies a touch event on a listView. This is the proper implementation:

```
@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (fabMenu.isExpanded()) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            fabMenu.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if(!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                fabMenu.collapse();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Works anywhere on the application and not just a listView. Place it in your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.8.0'`

and have floating Actions Menu and want to close menu after clicking anywhere on the screen try this

floatingActionsMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (floatingActionsMenu.isExpanded())
            floatingActionsMenu.collapse();
        return false;
    }
});
```

false <- makes view to continue scrolling

Comment: Can you explain what is "listView" here?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if (fam_main.isOpened()){
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            fam_main.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())){
                fam_main.close(true);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

***note
fam_main is your FAB menu id [FloatingActionMenu](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)